# heredoc synthax interfering with my bbcode parser output

Tags: php

I have attempted to use the heredoc syntax to delimit strings  without any special handling of quotes, as shown below. It appears the heredoc function is interfering with the ability of the bbcode function to parse the code as i am getting this error notice: Notice: Undefined variable: tag, when i view the code output in a browser. I need clues to resolve this.

Thanks.

```
function phpbbcode($s)
{
$s = str_replace("]\n", "]", $s);
$match = array('#\[php\](.*?)\[\/php\]#se');
$replace = array("'<div>'.highlight_string(stripslashes('$1'), true).'</div>'");
return preg_replace($match, $replace, $s);
}
// apply bbcode to highlight string
 $s = <<< parser
[php]
<?php
while(strpos($tag, \' =\') > 0) $tag = str_replace(\' =\', \'=\', $tag);
while(strpos($tag, \'= \') > 0) $tag = str_replace(\'= \', \'=\', $tag);
while(strpos($tag, \', \') > 0) $tag = str_replace(\', \', \',\', $tag);
while(strpos($tag, " ,") > 0) $tag = str_replace(\' ,\', \',\', $tag);
?>  
[/php]
parser;
echo  phpbbcode($s);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are expanded in a heredoc. If you don't want variables to be expanded, you should use a [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc). This is like a heredoc, but you put the identifer in single quotes:

```
 $s = <<< 'parser'
[php]
<?php
while(strpos($tag, \' =\') > 0) $tag = str_replace(\' =\', \'=\', $tag);
while(strpos($tag, \'= \') > 0) $tag = str_replace(\'= \', \'=\', $tag);
while(strpos($tag, \', \') > 0) $tag = str_replace(\', \', \',\', $tag);
while(strpos($tag, " ,") > 0) $tag = str_replace(\' ,\', \',\', $tag);
?>  
[/php]
parser;
```